# Restore Wordpress site based on files from server?

Tags: php, wordpress

An old domain of mine has expired and I'm having a hard time redeeming it (long story, not worth your time). I had a WP site running on it which is now inaccessible. Is there any way to recover the site from the files from the server, i.e. recreate the site on a new domain that has a new WP installation using the files on the server?

Comment: most of what you want i would guess is in the database

Answer (score -1):

You can simply point another domain to the server and change the domain name in `wp-config.php` and in your database (wp_options table).